# How do LocalBitcoin's merchants prevent volatility risk?

Tags: trading, price-volatility, arbitrage, localbitcoins

For example, how does a Bitcoin merchant (someone who buys and sells Bitcoin as a business type deal to make commission) prevent the losses induced by the volatility in the market? I.e., say you buy a Bitcoin on an exchange worth $10,000, and then list it on LocalBitcoins, and the price of Bitcoin drops to $9,500 in the mean time. Now your say 2% commission doesn't cover the cost of the price drop. Do traders just eat these losses and par them off as luck, or is there a way to peg their movements so that they are unaffected by this volatility?